# Change filtering method used by Firefox when zooming

Tags: windows, firefox, images

I often zoom in a step or two when reading long texts in Firefox, but when I do so the images become super blurry. It's not really a big deal but when reading text on images (mathematical equations mostly), it's a bit distracting.

It seems as if they are scaled using only bilinear interpolation. If I scale an image the same amount in for example [Paint.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint.NET) or Photoshop the result is much better.

Is there any way to change the filtering method used by Firefox to bicubic or another better method?

I am Using Firefox 3.5 on Windows BTW.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to zoom the text, and not the images, this article describes [Text Zoom](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/how-do-i-use-zoom):

**To resize screen text:**

First, at the top of the Firefox windowon the menu bar, click the View menu, scroll to the Zoom sub-menu, and select Zoom Text Only.

You may then zoom only the text while using the keyboard (ctrl +-0) or the mouse (ctrl scroll-wheel).

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what i was looking for but small sharp text is better than big blurry. Thanks :)